# Conditional Formatting of a Cell Based on Color Value in that Cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, conditional-formatting

Is is possible to format a cell based on one component of the RGB value inside of it. For example, let's say I have 3 cells - A1, A2, A3. In A1, I want the cell color to be the shade of red anywhere between 0 and 255 of the number in the cell (so if it is 128, it should be like half red). For that given cell, the other values will just be 0, 0 (so in this case, zero green and zero blue).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mimic this in Excel 2007/2010 by using a formatting rule over the range in question:

- Two-color scale
- Minimum of type number with value 0 and color black (or white, your choice)
- Maximum of type number with value 255 and color red

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty good!