# Excel: setting the color of a cell based upon a value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to set the color of a cell based upon a hex string (e.g., "RRGGBB") or a numeric value and if so how?  I have a sheet that converts colors that are stored in BGR format to RGB.  I would like would to set the cell color next to the converted RGB value.

Comment: What version of Excel? 2003, 2007, or 2010?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional Formatting of a Cell Based on Color Value in that Cell in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/150902/conditional-formatting-of-a-cell-based-on-color-value-in-that-cell-in-excel)

Comment: @Mehper I think it's a different question.

Comment: @Sux2Lose: I thought conditional formatting answers lordhog's question, doesn't it?

Comment: Conditional formatting actually is the way to go about it.

Comment: The question linked was about keeping G and B constant and using conditional formatting on the R value. OP's question is a situation where all three are variable, no? At least I'm not sure how to answer it w/ conditional formatting.

Comment: Sorry, I am using Excel 2007 in this particular case.  I was checking out the conditional formatting which has six cases.  The closes one is "Format all cells based on their values", but even a 3-color scale is basically a gradient.  The one that might be it, though I don't know how, is "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".  I don't think conditional formatting will work in this case, though I definitely could be wrong.  My current thought is this can only be done with a macro.  I have tried, but without success so far.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use VBA to accomplish your goal. Feel free to modify the routine below, which colors the background of the current cell, according to your needs.

```
Sub ColorGrey()
    ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
End sub
```

Comment: I am getting the error 1004 ("Application-defined or object-defined error") when I use the above code.

Comment: @lordhog, I tested it in Excel 2003 and it worked great, but you can probably peruse the 2007 help files to see if the syntax has changed.  Remember that a cell would probably have to be selected for ActiveCell to work.

Comment: Also works in 2007. Nice job.

Comment: Obviously, I doing something wrong.  I create a function like "Public Function SetCellColor(r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer)" with the code listed, then for a given cell I use "=SetCellColor(HEX2DEC(A1), HEX2DEC(A2), HEX2DEC(A3) )". I will get error 1004.  Strange, if I use "ActiveCell.Cells.Borders.Color = RGB(r, g, b)" instead of the code listed it will change the active cell's border color, but it is not changing the cell that has the equation in it. I think error 1004 (from reading) is due to the cell not being activated. I am looking for the cell with the equation to change color

Comment: Have you tried to use Activesheet.Range("A1") in place of ActiveCell? What does it happen?